# How to read web.config file in .Net Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, connection-string

I have created a .Net Core API and I referenced a .Net framework application to it. The referenced Application connects to a data base and its connection string is stored in web.config file:

```
    string CONNSTR =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SHOPPINGCNN"].ConnectionString;
```

The .Net Core application uses appsettings.json instead of web.config file. When I run the API and try to use the referenced application resources, the above code will be triggered and will return null because there is no web.config file exists in .net Core app. What is the best solution to resolve this issue

Comment: you can add a web config

Comment: I already did but I didn't get the connection string

Comment: It would more .net-core-app-like approach to store connection string in appsettings.json.

Comment: @Zuhair did you solve the problem?

Comment: I found the solution. I changed the name of the `Web.config` to `app.config` and I was able to get the connection string using:  
  
  
  
          `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SHOPPINGCNN"].ConnectionString`

The `app.config` file looks like this:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>
          <connectionStrings>
            <add name="SHOPPINGCNN" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;database=xxxxx" />
          </connectionStrings>
        </configuration>`

Comment: @Zuhair, please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Zuhair, it's odd, you should be able to post answers regardless of your level of reputation, maybe you should contact SO support.

Comment: Do we know why this works - or if it's a good idea?

Comment: @niico my guess is the difference between how a Web.config is handled with IIS/Express vs. how .NET Core/Standard handle a Web.config (which seems to be basically "ignore it").

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because .Net Core applications are self hosted and can almost run on any platform, they are no longer hosted on IIS. The .Net Core application settings are stored in a `Json` format (`appsettings.json`) by default while .Net Framework application configurations are stored in a `web.config` file in `XML` format. For more info about .Net Core applications, you may read [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=basicconfiguration). In my case, I was trying to access the data layer of a .Net Framework assembly from a .Net Core 2.0 assembly. To achieve this, there is no need to install [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) package in the .Net Core application but you only need to add `app.config` to the .Net Core assembly then add the connection string to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SHOPPINGCNN" connectionString="server=your server name;integrated security=true;database=your database name" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

After that, everything will work fine. Make sure that you use the same connection string name (`SHOPPINGCNN` in my case) that you used in your .Net Framework application otherwise you will not get the desired result. I did this in my project and it works 100%.

Comment: I have similar requirement where in had to read value from configuration file.. Does this work for function app (NET Core 2.0 Azure Functions) as well as it is a class library. I have done everything as mentioned but the value is coming as null.

Comment: Reference to `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package is required in the .net core application. Otherwise will get a runtime error the moment control is passed from .net core to a legacy .net app, before anything is read. Otherwise great answer!

Answer (score 13):

in .net core you can use `ConfigurationBuilder` to read appsettings.json file.

You can implement like following.

**appsettings.json sample**

```
{
  "option1": "value1_from_json",
  "option2": 2,

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "YourConnectionString": "............."
  }
}
```

**C# code sample**

```
static class YourClass
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
         var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

         Configuration = builder.Build();
         var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString"];

    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with you that we can store the connection string inside `appsettings.json` but thats the case when you are connecting to a database using `.Net Core` application but, in my case, Im referencing a `.Net Framework` application, which uses 

   `public static  string CONNSTR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SHOPPINGCNN"].ConnectionString;`


in its DataAccess class thus trying to use a resource from that application in my `Core` application the above code will be triggered and will return null value because there is no connection string exist in a `Web.config ` file

Comment: @Zuhair to keep connection string in best practice, you should try to keep it in appsettings.json file which is default configuration file of .net core

Comment: I already explained why Im using the old style configuration file. What would you do if you are referencing .Net Framework assembly that is getting its connection string using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`?. It cant get its connection string using .Net Core standards. What do you think?

Comment: @hasan, that was helpful.

Comment: Does this mean I need to execute that code in each class where I will be referencing a connection string?

Comment: You can make this class and its GetConnectionString() method static to use it in class where you import it

Answer (score 11):

In case you missed it - and because @Zuhair doesn't seem to want to post an answer - here is a copy paste of their solution (I missed this at first as it was only in a comment):

> I found the solution. I changed the name of the Web.config to
>   app.config and I was able to get the connection string using:
>
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SHOPPINGCNN"].ConnectionString
>
> The app.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"> encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="SHOPPINGCNN" connectionString="server=.\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security=true;database=xxxxx" /> 
</connectionStrings> 
</configuration>
```

You also need to install this NuGet package:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

In my case I simply renamed the web.config containing the connectionString 'app.config' and it worked.

I realise this probably isn't a good long term solution but for mixed legacy projects - or to get a foot in the door to begin to learn .net Core it's very useful.

Answer (score 9):

For .NET Core apps, the best way is to use the [Configuration API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration). This is a very flexible way and, thanks to providers pattern, it allows to use a different sources, not only the most common `appsettings.json` file (that by the way just a JSON file and could be named in a random way):

> - File formats (INI, JSON, and XML)
> - Command-line arguments
> - Environment variables
> - In-memory .NET objects
> - An encrypted user store Azure Key Vault
> - Custom providers, which you install or create

---

Now about `ConfigurationManager` . At first, the .NET Core forced to forget about this class - it was not implemented and supported and the idea was to fully replace it by providing new Configuration API.

Moreover, the reality is that ASP.NET Core apps aren't hosted via IIS anymore (IIS works mainly as a reverse proxy now), and so the `web.config` is not so useful anymore (unless rare cases when you still need to define parameters specific to IIS configuration).

Though, after the .NET Standard 2.0 was provided, this  [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) nuget package is available and brings back the `ConfigurationManager` class. It became possible due to new [compatibility shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464937/compatibility-shim-used-by-net-standard-2-0) implemented in new .NET Core 2.0.

Regarding your case, it is difficult to say why you have 'null' as it not enough information:

- it may be a wrong section in web.config
- web.config may not be copied into your output/publishing folder

Comment: I added

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`
along with Web.config, but still cant get the connection string.

Comment: same here, appsettings is always empty

Comment: Ever come up with a solution?

Comment: I changed my Web.config to App.config and my issues resolved immediately.

Comment: Fixed my problem that App.config was not setup to copy to output directory. But I'll look into Configuration API for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the OP has a data access layer project library that targets the full .Net Framework that contains code which depends on the **ConfigurationManager**. **ConfigurationManager** knows nothing about configuration in .Net Core and thus cannot access values from the default configuration implementation, i.e. **appsettings.json**. Some answers note that you can add an **app.config** file to the .Net Core client, but this smells if we don't hold our nose.

The better solution would be to inject the connection string into the data access library. Especially if that library will be used by multiple clients.

Answer (score -1):

For everyone having problem reading web.config in asp.net **core**. After spending hours trying and failing.. then i came to a blog which stated

> The .Net Core application uses appsettings.json instead of web.config
>   file.

so i suggest everyone to place files they want to read to appsettings.json and from there you can read. There are plenty of methods available. Just wanted to save time of those trying.

Comment: The ConfigurationManager code OP is referring to is in a different project that targets the full .Net framework. It will not have access to any configuration values that are a part of the appsettings.json in his .Net Core project.

Answer (score -1):

The only way i could use a web.config was reading the file as a XML, and inputing the values into a ConfigurationManager object using the .AddInMemoryCollection(list) method.

```
//ConfigurationManager.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace sql_util {
    public static class ConfigurationManager {
        public static IConfiguration AppSettings { get; }
        static ConfigurationManager() {
            var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
            xd.Load(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "web.config");
            if (xd.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings").Count > 0) {
                XmlNodeList confs = xd.GetElementsByTagName("appSettings")[0].ChildNodes;
                for (int y = 0; y < confs.Count; y++) {
                    if (confs[y].Attributes != null) {
                        if (confs[y].Attributes[0] != null) {
                            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(confs[y].Attributes[0].Value, confs[y].Attributes[1].Value));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            AppSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddXmlFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Web.config", false, true)
                    .AddInMemoryCollection(list)
                    .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//Web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="smtp_server" value="127.0.0.1" />
```

---

```
//envia_mail.cs
using ConfigurationManager = sql_util.ConfigurationManager;
namespace anotacoes {
    public class envia_email {
        private string SmtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_server"];
```

Answer (score -1):

added Web.config file to root as i used in .net framework project.

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySQL"]; works fine.

I changed my Web.config to App.config and my issues resolved immediately.

Answer (score -1):

You can still use an app.config for connection strings if needed. Include the nuget package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.

Then to get a connection string you'd do this:

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

As others have pointed out, connection strings are easily used from the appsettings.json file and this is the preferred method.