# Cannot access web.config of ASP.NET Core Web API using ConfigurationManager in VS2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

The scenario is I created a class library for database connection. I also installed the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` in this library.

Here is the code where the `web.config` access takes place:

```
public static class SqlDataAccess
{
    public static string GetConnectionString(string name)
    {
        string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
        return strCon;
    }
}
```

And this is the code where I output the connection string.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        string connString = SqlDataAccess.GetConnectionString("db");
        return connString;
    }
}
```

When I access the `WeatherForecast` API, it should print out the connection string. But instead printing it out, it prints out an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The `web.config` file is in the ASP.NET Core Web API project and I added the class library as project reference.

This is the content of the `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="db" connectionString="{my connection string is in here}"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have seen answers regarding this problem, but they still did not work in my case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read web.config file in .Net Core app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996480/how-to-read-web-config-file-in-net-core-app)

Answer (score 0):

I used your given code and wrote a test controller, the only difference here was adding the configure file and naming it as **app.config**. Here is the result of my testing here, which is able to get the value form the file:
[image]

If you insist using **web.config**, which is created while you publishing your project, I may recommend you adding the value in **appsettings.json** instead of adding it in **web.config**.